# jquery .css() is only setting the first matching style value found

Tags: jquery, dynamic, css

This one isn't making any sense to me.

I am attempting to use jquery .css() to set the "min-height" of some buttons based on the window height.

For whatever reason, it is only setting the min-height for the FIRST button matching, but there are 16 matching buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/20/embedded/result/

"#tab-btn-2" is the problem. Thiss is the javascript I'm using:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function(){
  setMaxHeight();
  $( window ).bind( "resize", setMaxHeight ); 

  function setMaxHeight() {
    $( "#tab-content-1" ).css( "max-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );
    $( "#tab-content-1" ).css( "min-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );
    $( "#tab-content-2" ).css( "max-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );
    $( "#tab-content-2" ).css( "min-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );
    $( "#tab-content-3" ).css( "max-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );
    $( "#tab-content-3" ).css( "min-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" ); 
    $( "#tab-btn-2" ).css( "min-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );

  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Id's must be unique. http://jsfiddle.net/VDtgT/21/ The alert shows you have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: Why don't you set the CSS by using a class if all of the divs (I suppose you are using divs) are going to be the same height for example: instead of $("#tab-content-n") have $(".tab-content") this will make it shorter, and of course you can leave the ID to reference them individually later.

Comment: @SamuelLopez tab-content-n is a bit different than tab-btn-n. The first two content containers are the same, but the last one will have unique properties. I could combine for the first two though. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinB thanks, id vs. class was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's are unique, and jQuery will only find the first element with a particular ID, as there should be only one.

You'll need to use a class instead.

```
$( ".tab-btn-2" ).css( ....
```

Comment: @JG707 - No reason to feel silly, this comes up ten times every day, so it's a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to give each of your buttons the same class name and use the class to set the min-height (vs. the id).  Your ids should be unique for each element on the page.

```
<input type=button id=whatever class="tab-btn-2" />
...
$( ".tab-btn-2" ).css( "min-height", ( $( window ).height() * 0.67 | 0 ) + "px" );
```